# Why does TypeScript allow "this" to be omitted when in a method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following TypeScript compiles without errors:

```
class Something {

    name: string;

    constructor() {
        name = "test";
    }

}
```

This code compiles without errors, seemingly believing that the name variable exists. However it produces js which will not run, because I have omitted the **`this`** keyword:

```
/Users/cburtbrown/Documents/code/ts/js/tstest.js:6
        console.log(name);
                    ^

ReferenceError: name is not defined
    at Something.action (/Users/cburtbrown/Documents/code/ts/js/tstest.js:6:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/cburtbrown/Documents/code/ts/js/tstest.js:10:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:159:18)
    at node.js:444:3
```

If I mistype the variable in the constructor then it fails with this error:

```
Cannot find name 'namej'
```

Shouldn't this error occur even if the variable is spelled correctly?

Comment: Works for me. The JS version runs with no error on node 6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [the `window` object has a `name` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

As far as TypeScript is concerned, you're attempting to assign a value to this property. Of course, this will fail when you aren't running in a browser.

You can test this for yourself by trying to assign a value [to any other `window` properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

Example:

```
class Something {
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        status = "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, so it's specifically `name`. Didn't consider that possibility. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Compiles fine on node 6.0, no `window` here.

Comment: @C14L He said it compiles fine but fails to run correctly. If you aren't using strict mode then it will run because you create an implicit global.